# How to run a scenario with dynamic table for different base url without duplicating the tests in same feature using Karate

Tags: api, automation, automated-tests, karate

```
Feature: scenario outline using a dynamic table

Background:
   * def kittens = read('../callarray/kittens.json')

Scenario Outline: cat name: <name>
   Given url demoBaseUrl
   And path 'cats'
   And request { name: '#(name)' }
   When method post
   Then status 200
   And match response == { id: '#number', name: '#(name)' }

   # the single cell can be any valid karate expression
   # and even reference a variable defined in the Background
   Examples:
   | kittens |
```

I would like to run the same test with different base URLs without duplicating the tests ,so it passes for different brands. Please help.